# How to get back from TTY to Unity

Tags: unity, tty

I got a problem. I installed SDL, rebooted pc, and got to GNOME-terminal or in other name it's TTY I guess so. I tried to reboot again, but I get the same screen. Could someone help me how to get out of TTY and get back to Unity (Desktop)?

Comment: It is @Arman - Ainis, please mark the other as answered, or ask for more help - and for this you can answer your own question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I you try Ctrl+Alt+F7you should return to Unity

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work, I fixed it anyways, I used startx command, but before that I reinstalled xorg server. Anyways thanks for response. :)